# Overriding django_admin's list_display into cascadingdropdown style

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, overriding, cascadingdropdown

I've been searching this for days, got some progress but something stop me. 
I'm trying to override the django xadmin's list_display into "Chained Select Boxes"/"Cascading dropdown list" style, like the "country state city".
i've add some select javascript into '/xadmin/views/model_list.html'
but i do not know how can i transfer the data result from my database into this javascript. 
Anybody could show me? thanks in advance.

```html
{% extends base_template %}
{% load i18n %}

{% load xadmin_tags %}

{% block extrastyle %}
<style type="text/css">
  .btn-toolbar{margin-top: 0;}
  #content-block.full-content{margin-left: 0;}
</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block bodyclass %}change-list{% endblock %}

{% block nav_title %}{% if brand_icon %}<i class="{{brand_icon}}"></i> {% endif %}{{brand_name}}{% endblock %}

{% block nav_toggles %}
{% include "xadmin/includes/toggle_menu.html" %}
{% if has_add_permission %}
  <a href="{{add_url}}" class="navbar-toggle pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
{% endif %}
<button class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".content-navbar .navbar-collapse">
  <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
</button>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav_btns %}
  {% if has_add_permission %}
    <a href="{{add_url}}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
    {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock nav_btns %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="content-toolbar btn-toolbar pull-right clearfix">
    {% view_block 'top_toolbar' %}
    {% block toolbar_column %}
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> {% trans "Columns" %} <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu model_fields pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="{{clean_select_field_url}}"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> {% trans "Restore Selected" %}</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        {% for f, selected, flink in model_fields %}
        <li><a href="{{flink}}">
          {% if selected %}<i class="fa fa-check"></i>{% else %}<i class="fa fa-blank"></i>{% endif %}
          {{f.verbose_name}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
    {% endblock toolbar_column %}
    {% block toolbar_layouts %}
    <div class="btn-group layout-btns" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm layout-normal active">
        <input type="radio"> <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm layout-condensed">
        <input type="radio"> <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
      </label>
      {% view_block 'top_layout_btns' %}
    </div>
    {% endblock toolbar_layouts %}
    {% block toolbar_fullscreen %}
    <div class="btn-group layout-btns" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm layout-full"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></button>
      {% view_block 'top_check_btns' %}
    </div>
    {% endblock toolbar_fullscreen %}
    {% view_block 'top_btns' %}
  </div>

  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm pagination-left pagination-inline">
    {% view_block 'pagination' 'small' %}
  </ul>
  
  <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% view_block 'result_list_form' %}>{% csrf_token %}
  {% view_block 'results_top' %}
  <div class="results table-responsive">
  {% if results %}
  {% block results_grid %}
 
    <div id="element_id">
        <span class="FirstClass">FirstClassScene：
          <select class="FirstClassScene">
              {% for o in result_headers.cells %}
              <option value="BeautySalon" >{{ o.field_name }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </span>
        <span class="SecondClass">SecondClassScene：
          <select class="SecondClassScene">
              {% for o in result_headers.cells %}
              <option value="hall" selected>{{ o.field_name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </span>
        <span class="ThirdClass">ThirdClassScene：
          <select class="ThirdClassScene">
              {% for o in result_headers.cells %}
              <option value="ConsultingRoom" selected>{{ o.field_name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </span>
    </div>
      <script src="jquery.cxselect.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
      <script>
      $('#element_id').cxSelect({
          url: 'cityData.min.json',               
          selects: ['FirstClassScene', 'SecondClassScene', 'ThirdClassScene'],  
          emptyStyle: 'none'
        });

      $(document).ready(function(){

 var FirstClassSelect = $(".FirstClass").children("select");
 var SecondClassSelect = $(".SecondClass").children("select");

 FirstClassSelect.change(function(){
  var FirstClassValue = $(this).val();
  if( FirstClassValue != ""){
   if(!FirstClassSelect.data(FirstClassValue)){
    $.post("ChainSelect",{keyword:FirstClassValue,type:"top"},function(data){
     if (data.length != 0){
      SecondClassSelect.html("");
      $("<option value=''>please choose</option>").appendTo(SecondClassSelect);
      for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++ ){
       $("<option value =' " + data[i] + " '> "+ data[i] +"</option>").appendTo(SecondClassSelect);
      }
      SecondClassSelect.parent().show();
      FirstClassSelect.next().show();
     }else{
      SecondClassSelect.parent().hide();
      FirstClassSelect.next().hide();
     }
     FirstClassSelect.data(FirstClassValue,data);
    },"json");
   }else{
    var data = FirstClassSelect.data(FirstClassValue);
    if (data.length != 0){
      SecondClassSelect.html("");
      $("<option value=''>please choose</option>").appendTo(SecondClassSelect);
      for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++ ){
       $("<option value =' " + data[i] + " '> "+ data[i] +"</option>").appendTo(SecondClassSelect);
      }
      SecondClassSelect.parent().show();
      FirstClassSelect.next().show();
     }else{
      SecondClassSelect.parent().hide();
      FirstClassSelect.next().hide();
     }
   }
  }else{
   SecondClassSelect.parent().hide();
   FirstClassSelect.next().hide();
  }
 });


      </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Share the code and sample which you tried to get the scope narrow down. The question is broad.

Comment: Thanks  @Rizwan . i've attached the code.